# Writing $\frac{1}{2}+i$ as $1+i+\frac{i^2}{2}$ in Needhams Complex Analysis text

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This question is from the first chapter of Needham's "Visual Complex Analysis Text"

[image]

*My question* is in regards to the sequence they get in the solution below.  Getting the first term in the sequence to be $1$ and the second being $1+i$, follows naturally, and when I think about the third term in the sequence it's clearly the complex number $\frac{1}{2}+i$.  How did they get the equivalent expression $1+i+\frac{i^2}{2}$?

**Solution**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author used the following equivalences:

$$\begin{align}\text{East} &: i^0 =i^4=i^{8\ }=...=1\\
\text{North} &: i^1 =i^5=i^{9\ }=...=i\\
\text{West} &: i^2 =i^6=i^{10}=...=-1\\
\text{South} &: i^3 =i^7=i^{11}=...=-i\end{align}$$

And in general $i^k = i^{k\ \  (\text{ mod } 4)}$.

It's worth mentioning also that multiplication by $i$ is a rotation by $90^o$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians. By multiplying the $n^{th}$ move by $i$ and dividing by $n+1$, you are following the presented algorithm.